# Must declae Scalar variable

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've been stuck on this error for a while, in vb.net trying to connect to SQL and pull data from a table within a day, using parameters to do this, a datetimepicker - the data saved to SQL is in a custom datetime format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,

When i execute my code i get "Must declare the scalar variable "@startdata". When i remove the code " and startdate >= @startdata  AND startdate < @enddata " it works but shows all the data without the date range as it should.

```
connect()
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT status, startdate, seconds FROM [sqlccmlinestatus] WHERE line = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' and startdate >= @startdata  AND startdate < @enddata "
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdata", DateTimePicker1.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddata", DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1))
    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    Dim dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString)
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dataAdapter.Fill(table)
    Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = table

    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1

    disconnect()

    DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = "28"

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 78
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 78
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Width = 95

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Status:"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Date:"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Seconds:"

    DataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
    DataGridView1.Rows(0).Selected = True
```

Any help would be great,

Many Thanks,
Pete

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `MySqlDataAdapter` instead of `SqlDataAdapter`?  Does the data provider you are using support named parameters?

Answer (score 0):

First avoid `line = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'`. Add a new parameter instead (this is a suggestion, this isn't the cause of your error).

Second add the `Date` part of DatePicker value

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT status, startdate, seconds FROM [sqlccmlinestatus] WHERE [line] = @line and startdate >= @startdata  AND startdate < @enddata "
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdata", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@line", ComboBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddata", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.AddDays(1))
```

this works if you want to check only the datepart.

A better way to do this would be declare the type of the parameter and assign the value

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdata",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=DateTimePicker1.Value;
```

if the `line` parameter doesn't work try with the [SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the combobox

instead `Text` property.

Comment: Thanks for the Changes, i changed for the line and also the parameters for the startdata, i've done the same thing for the enddata, but now the codes failing at "Must declare the scalar variable "line"." Cheers

Comment: try `cmd.Parameters.Add("@line",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value=ComboBox1.Text;`

Comment: Just tried it, no luck, still have the problem "Must declare the scalar variable "line" - Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know. Check which is the value of `SelectedText` or `SelectedItem`

Comment: is `line` a column of your table?

Comment: I've tried both with no avail. Yep "line" is a column of my table which at the moment is always "1".

Comment: which is the database type of line column?

Comment: varchar(100) i didnt set it as int due to not knowing what the other lines were going to be called.

Comment: try surrounding "line" with square brackets